# In Netbeans IDE, desired behavior is when i press b then space, it creates two curly brackets with cursor in middle

Tags: ide, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

when I press b-space for code block it does:

```
{
(cursor here)
}
```

How can I go about accomplishing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Tools/Options/Editor/Code Templates*. Create a new template for the letter b (*New*, type *b*, *Ok*), then type the following into *Expanded Text*:

```
{
    ${cursor}
}
```

Finally, set *Expand Template on* to *Space*.

By the way, you can get the same behavior by pressing {, and hitting an enter.